# Set up a redirect

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

There is a `mixin` in the view, where a slash is added to the url. It is necessary that when you open a non-existent page (for example,  example.com/index), immediately throw `404`, without `301` (so as not to add a slash at the end). Only a check on `404` status comes to mind, if there is one. Like if there is a page, then do not need to add a slash. If there is no such page, then to formally add a slash at the end (without a redirect). And if the status is `200`, then okay, and if not, then throw `404`.

```
def is_normal_slash_count(url):
    temp_url = url
    slash_count = 0
    while temp_url.endswith('/'):
        slash_count += 1
        temp_url = temp_url[:-1]
    return (slash_count == 1, slash_count)


def replace_bad_slash(url, slash_count):
    if slash_count == 2:
        return url.replace('//', '/')
    return url.replace('/'*(slash_count-1), '')


def normalize_url(url):
    if len(url) > 1:
        if not url.endswith('/'):
            return url + '/'
        # replace the url like /contacts//// to /contacts/
        good_slash, slash_count = is_normal_slash_count(url)
        if not good_slash:
            url = replace_bad_slash(url, slash_count)
    return url

def is_bad_url(url):
    if len(url) > 1:
        good_slash, slash_count = is_normal_slash_count(url)
        if not good_slash:
            return True
    return False

class RedirectMixinView:

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = self.request.path

        redirect_setting = RedirectSettings.objects.filter(url_from=url).first()
        if redirect_setting:
            return redirect(redirect_setting.url_to, permanent=True)

        if is_bad_url(url):
            return redirect(normalize_url(url), permanent=True)
        return super(RedirectMixinView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class LandingView(RedirectMixinView, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page = Page.objects.filter(url=self.request.path).first()
        # Show 404 page
        if not page:
            raise Http404
        return super(LandingView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Now, because of the mixin, a slash is added at the end of the url (for example, you enter example.com/blog, and redirects to example.com/blog/). We need to somehow configure the slash to be added only if the example.com/blog/ page exists. Just now, if there is no such page, then first adds a slash to the end (301 status) and only then 404. It is necessary that in this case there should be 404 immediately.

Comment: So far, only the use of `requests` comes to my mind and status checking.

Comment: Maybe you can just remove it. `if not url.endswith('/'):
            return url + '/'`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Then other functions in the mixin stop working. And I need them.

Comment: @dirkgroten It is necessary that the slash is added only if the page (with a slash) will not give a 404 error.

Comment: You can check if a url exists before redirecting to it by [resolving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) it yourself.

Comment: But note that many views also produce a 404 (e.g. the url pattern might match but the object id passed in the url doesn't exist). There's no way to know it in advance without actually calling the view. So what you want is not possible.

Comment: @dirkgroten I wrote `resolve(url)` and got `ResolverMatch(func=project.landing.views.LandingView, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=landing, app_names=[], namespaces=[])` in bot cases

Comment: Look at the docs: if it matches you get a `ResolverMatch` if it doesn't it raises an error (you would need to `try: except:` to catch that.

Comment: `resolve` gives nothing useful at all